# Rotate 'this' image on click - jQuery

Tags: jquery, rotation

I'm trying to get a simple image to rotate on click. This will apply to multpiple images so therefore i need to use `$(this)` tag within jQuery. I've tried this but it did not work:

```
$('.image').click(function(){
    $(this).rotate(180);
});
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/v6xtG/1/

I do not wish to add a CSS3 class as i need IE8 support

Comment: It looks like you might have been attempting to use the [jQuery Rotate](https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/) plugin. This functionality does not exist by default in jQuery as far as I know. If you are trying to use this plugin, you need to include the script on your page. Were you actually trying to use this plugin?

Answer (score 0):

you probably should include the jqueryrotate plugin, as jquery doesn't have a method called rotate out of the box.

https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/downloads/detail?name=jQueryRotate.js

Answer (score 0):

Use `transform:rotate(180deg)`

```
$('.image').click(function(){
    $(this).css("transform","rotate(180deg)");
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6xtG/5/)

Comment: is there a way of returning it on a second click?

Comment: Isnt that a [CSS3 feature](http://www.cssrotate.com/)?  The op mentioned that they did not want CSS3

Comment: for IE use -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);

Comment: @sTACKoVERFLOW That will only work in IE9+ which does not fit the OPs requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Using jqueryrotate.js http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js

Jquery

```
$('.image').click(function(){
$(this).rotate(180);
});
```

Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9FMks/

Answer (score 0):

**[Live Demo with multiple angles](http://jsfiddle.net/v6xtG/9/)**

apply reference of **jQueryRotate.js** OR use this scrip in your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js"></script>
```